# Push failed : Invalid type: Schema.object__mdt Error message when pushing the code from VS Code to Scratch Org

Tags: lightning-web-components, push

I have create a custom metadata object with records in my DevHub org and i write an apex method that get the custom metadata records but i got an error message in my terminal when i try to push my code to Scratch org 
`Invalid type: Schema.myObject__mdt`.
Additionally, i face the same issue when i add roles in my DevHub and i push my code to scratch orh there is no error message appear but the roles that i create in the DevHub org did not appear in my combobox role list.

Comment: Did you actually download ALL of the related metadata? The files must be on your computer, not in the DevHub org.

Comment: No i did not download related Metadata on my computer